# Springboot Controller redirect not working

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am trying a quick prototype using Spring boot.

I have the following Controller code minus the imports

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@RestController
@Controller
public class IndexController{
    @RequestMapping(value = "/")
    public ModelAndView firstPage(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("index");
        mv.addObject("message", Calendar.getInstance().getTime().toString());
        return mv;
    }
    @RequestMapping(value="/gotoNextPage",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public  ModelAndView gotoNextPage(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
        System.out.println("Inside gotoNextPage!!!!!!");
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("redirect:nextpage");
        mv.addObject("message", "next page");
        return mv;
    }
}
```

**From my HTML, I invoke the /gotoNextPage and in my Server, I see the Inside gotoNextPage!!!! print statement. However, the nextPage doesn't load. If I don't use redirect and I type http://localhost:8080/gotoNextPage, the HTML content loads fine. Also, the index.html also loads fine**

I am using spring boot mvc, thymeleaf, angularjs

My project structure is shown below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCcVP.png)

My POM XML file dependencies are shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>ng-spring-boot-helloworld</groupId>
    <artifactId>ng-spring-boot-helloworld</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
                <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.7.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A redirect is client side, so what you pass after the `redirect:` should lead to a valid URL not a view name... And stop mixing versions you are mixing Spring Boot 1.2.0 and 1.2.7. Change the parent to 1.2.7 and remove the versions elsewhere.

Comment: @M.Deinum: Thanks for bringing up the discrepancy in version numbers. I have corrected that. I changed the redirect to say ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("redirect:nextpage.html"); and also moved the nextpage.html under the static folder in my project structure. It doesn't work. I also tried "redirect:/nextpage.html". Both of them didn't work. I tried http://localhost:8080/nextpage.html and the content loads up fine.

Comment: You have both `@RestController` and `@Controller` which is it... Judging from your return types you need `@Controller` not `@RestController`. Also the `@EnableAutoConfiguration` is useless on this class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd try to simplify the method to use `Model` and return a simple `String`:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/gotoNextPage",method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String gotoNextPage(Model model){
    LOG.debug("Inside gotoNextPage!!!!!!");
    model.addAttribute("message", "next page");
    return "redirect:nextpage.html";
}
```

Comment: I tried your code. That isn't working. I have placed the nextpage.html in the static folder. The function is being hit and I see the sys out. But the page isn't redirecting.

Comment: It seems that you do have a different issue. Can you check the Http headers? Can you get the nextpage when you open it in the browser directly?

Comment: Yes. I am able to open the page directly on the browser. Also in my controller method, if I don't use redirect, I am able to invoke the contents of nextpage directly when I type /gotoNextPage on the browser. The other thing that is baffling me is if I type redirect:www.google.com, I don't see google.com on my browser either. It seems like the controller is able to redirect but the browser is not reloading the page. Am I missing any configuration in the property file? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @supreethmurthy, you should use full URL, like this `redirect:http://www.google.com` for redirect to external page.

Comment: I looked at the http headers. I am getting a status of 200, which is correct. But I am making a call through XmlHttpRequest on the client side. Could that be causing the problem?

Comment: But 200 is incorrect. You are expecting a redirect and therefore you should get a 302. Do you maybe have a catchall clause in another method or controller in your app?

Comment: @hrrgttnchml: Thanks for your suggestion. I looked at the http header as you suggested. I was making a calling through $http.get in angular. I had to handle the event myself. I changed my JS call to do a window.location.href and it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use [RedirectView](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/RedirectView.html) explicite

```
@RequestMapping(value="/gotoNextPage",method = RequestMethod.GET)
public  ModelAndView gotoNextPage(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
    System.out.println("Inside gotoNextPage!!!!!!");

    ModelMap model = new ModelMap();
    model.add("message", "next page");
    return new ModelAndView(
       new RedirectView("/nextpage", true),
       //or new RedirectView("/nextpage.html", true),
       model
    );
}
```

Comment: I tried redirecting to another controller method instead of an html file and the redirected controller method is hit. I see a sys out from the new method. In the new method, I tried redirect, forward and also generic way like this. ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("nextpage");
        mv.addObject("message", Calendar.getInstance().getTime().toString());
        return mv; This isn't working either. From the new controller, the page isn't loaded. There is no error on the console either.

Comment: It's old but reading this I would say that the browser has reached the final result, while your spring application continued the execution..

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use "redirect:" with springboot,You must inject "InternalResourceViewResolver".Although Spring Boot provides auto-configuration,if you use "@EnableWebMvc","InternalResourceViewResolver" will not inject.[look here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-auto-configuration)

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to redirect and it does not work, remember that you mustn't put the `@ResponseBody` annotation.

So, this **will not** work:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/agregar")
@ResponseBody // Annotation here
public String guardarProducto() {
    // magic here
    return "redirect:/productos/mostrar";
}
```

But this **will do** (remove the `@ResponseBody` Annotation):

```
@PostMapping(value = "/agregar")
public String guardarProducto() {
    // magic here
    return "redirect:/productos/mostrar";
}
```

More info about redirect in Spring Boot [here](https://parzibyte.me/blog/en/2019/08/26/how-to-redirect-spring-boot/).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was making a call through xmlhttprequest object on the client end. I had to handle the completion of the event. I got rid of the $http.get call on the client and did a window.location.href instead. My controller redirects and the page loads automatically.